# Go to row variable in other field

Tags: vba, excel-2010, rows, copy-paste

I have 2 worksheets, `Master` and `Temporary`.

On `Temporary`, a single row is filled with data, eg `LineNr`, `CustomerName`, `Opportunity`, `Sales`. I use this row to make changes to the data in the fields.

The `Master` sheet has a list of about 25 rows (`A3:A27`) with data similar to `Temporary` and in the same layout. I copy/paste from the line in the `Master` sheet onto the `Temporary` sheet.

Dependent on the `LineNr` on the `Temporary` sheet, I need to automatically copy the row (`A3:D3`), find the corresponding row on `Master`, and paste the values in there.

I can't find how to select the correct row on `Master` and to get this pasted.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Why can't you edit the data directly in the master?

Comment: Have you looked at the `VLOOKUP` function?

Answer (score 0):

Create a button (insert shape) on the temp sheet. Right-mouse click on it, select Assign Macro, and click New.  Insert this code:

```
With Worksheets("Master").Range("A3:A27")
    Set cell = .Find(Worksheets("Temporary").Range("A3").Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Master").Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets("Temporary").Range("B3").Value
        Worksheets("Master").Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2).Value = Worksheets("Temporary").Range("C3").Value
        Worksheets("Master").Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 3).Value = Worksheets("Temporary").Range("D3").Value
    End If
End With
```

This assumes you have unique row numbers... otherwise it'll update only the first one it finds.